# Using xib programatically setting IBOutlet and file owner results in key value coding-compliant error

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, xib, key-value

I create a xib. The file owner of the xib is a set to a custom class called `PackageTrackingListViewElement`. The `PackageTrackingListViewElement` has an IBOutlet property called `contentView`, among others. Several views in interface builder are connected to the IBOutlet properties of the custom class called `PackageTrackingListViewElement`.

I try to initialize an object from the xib.

```
PackageTrackingListViewElement *element2 = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"PackageTrackingListViewElementXib" owner:nil options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];

[element2.labelDate setText:@"12/14/15"];
[element2.labelLocation setText:@"Berkeley, California"];
```

After this, I add the `element2` object to a UIStackView.

**What am I supposed to set the file owner in** `loadNibNamed` **so that I do not get the error that the owner of the xib is not key-value compliant for the properties I am attempting to access?**

My error is `[<UIStackView 0x165ddc80> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key contentView.'` When I try to set the stackView as the owner of the xib. I know this is wrong of course, but I cannot set the object which has not been created to be its own owner. I do not understand what to do.

Comment: What should I set the file-owner of the xib to to make the properties of that class accessible externally in a view controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alas figured it out. Many thanks to [Instantiating a UIView from a XIB file with itself as the file's owner?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23797326/instantiating-a-uiview-from-a-xib-file-with-itself-as-the-files-owner)

Thank you [nebs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/316891/nebs)

**PackageTrackingListViewElement.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface PackageTrackingListViewElement : UIView

@property (nonatomic,strong) IBOutlet UILabel *labelLocation;

- (instancetype)initFromNib;

@end
```

**PackageTrackingListViewElement.m**

```
#import "PackageTrackingListViewElement.h"

@implementation PackageTrackingListViewElement : UIView

- (instancetype)initFromNib {
    return [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:NSStringFromClass(self.class) owner:nil options:nil] firstObject];
}

@end
```

You can then simply do:

```
PackageTrackingListViewElement *myView = [[PackageTrackingListViewElement alloc] initFromNib];


[myView.labelLocation setText:@"text"]; //access properties
```

By using the instantiation procedure in the link above, I got my instantiation of the xib to work. I set the file-owner of the xib to nothing (NSObject), and instead set the root view (by selecting the view in the xib) to the PackageTrackingListViewElement and connecting all outlets to that view.

Comment: Thank you for this, though its a little over a year old!